# JPA/Hibernate/Querydsl can't sql order Entity data class name Order

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, querydsl, pageable

I request Order Index Pageable that contain sort condition example (id, desc)

**request url**

```
/orders?page=0&size=20&sort=id,desc
```

**error message**

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Invalid path: 'order.id' [select order1
from com.mystore.domain.Order order1
order by order.id desc]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Invalid path: 'order.id' [select order1
from com.mystore.domain.Order order1
order by order.id desc]] with root cause

org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Invalid path: 'order.id' [select order1
from com.mystore.domain.Order order1
```

I test change `@Entity(name="otherOrder")` but not working

but another entity name pageable with sort working properly
for example seller, account, product

**orderClass**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="orders")
data class Order(
        @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        val id: Long = 0,
        @Column(unique = true)
        val merchantUid: String) {}
```

**orderController**

```
@GetMapping
@ApiPageable
fun index(searchOrder: SearchOrder, pageable: Pageable): Page<Any> {
    return orderService.findAllWithSearchAndPageable(searchOrder, pageable)
}
```

**orderService**

```
fun findAllWithSearchAndPageable(searchOrder: SearchOrder, pageable: Pageable): Page<Any> {
    return orderRepository.findAllWithSearchAndPageable(searchOrder, pageable)
}
```

**orderRepositoryImpl**

```
@Autowired
lateinit var jpaQueryFactory: JPAQueryFactory

fun findAllWithSearchAndPageable(serarchOrder: SearchOrder, pageable: Pageable): PageImpl<Any> {
    val query = jpaQueryFactory.select(order)
            .from(order)
    val orders = querydsl!!.applyPagination(pageable, query).fetch()

    return PageImpl(orders as List<Any>, pageable, query.fetchCount())
}
```

change Order -> OtherNameOther is one solution
have the other solution?

Comment: What is the content of orders after  val orders = querydsl!!.applyPagination(pageable, query).fetch()

Comment: @SimonMartinelli after val orders is list<Order>

Comment: and there is data inside?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli inside return example

list<Order>

Order { 
    id="1"
    merchantUid = "helloworld"
}